# jQuery click() event isn't fired after sorting table

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html-table

When you load the page, if you click on a line, it logs to the console `clicked`.

But, if you sort the table (click on the table header), click event on `tr` doesn't get fired if you try to click on the rows.

I'm using this plugin: [tablefixedheader](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/)

***jQuery***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("table.ex").fixheadertable({
        caption        : 'Tarefas Dispon&iacute;veis',
        showhide    : false,
        height        : '265',
        zebra       : true,
        zebraClass  : 'ui-state-default',
        sortable    : true,
        sortedColId : 0,
        dateFormat  : 'Y/m/d',
        pager        : true,
        rowsPerPage    : 25,
        colratio    : [110,150],
        minColWidth : 110,
        resizeCol    : true
    });

    // problem with this click
    // The event isn't triggered:

    $("table.ex tr").click(function(){
        console.log('clicked');
    });

});
```

**DEMO**  http://jsfiddle.net/QpU3c/

Comment: Links are fine, but always post the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I added the event that isn't getting triggered :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I had to use jsfiddle because it is using some external resources (css/js)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was adding the code but **thecodeparadox** was faster than me. Thanks one more time, always learning!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), because the plugin changes the original `tr` elements, so they lose their attached event handlers. The handler should be attached on the table itself, because it is certainly not changing.

```
$("table.ex").on('click', 'tr', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/QpU3c/2/)

Comment: Just brillant, thank you !! It resolves the issue with both sorting and pagination.

Comment: @kapa If I could hug you I would.

Comment: @BernieDavies It makes me happy, let's pretend it happened :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$("table.ex").on('click', 'tr', function(){
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QpU3c/1/)**

---

#### Note

You need delegate event, because when you're sorting the `table`, `.fixheadertable()` removes the `tr`s and again append it to table newly. So after sorting those `tr`s are treated as dynamic element.

---

Syntax of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) for delegate event is like:

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```