# I want to click tr after sort table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[jQuery click() event isn't fired after sorting table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142500/jquery-click-event-isnt-fired-after-sorting-table)

I read this. I have same problem.
They had told that can solve problem to write like

```
$("#0 tbody").on('click', 'tr', function()
```

But, If i write `.on` instead .click, I get error like this.

> "object don't support 'on'property or method"

I checked [on] in jquery-1.10.2.js file. 
And wrote there `[on: function( types, selector, data, fn, /*INTERNAL*/ one )]`

I searched how to use `.on` in **jquery-1.10.2**, But i can't get solution yet.

If you know solution, please teach me. thank you.

Comment: How do we execute this ?

Comment: run this to see what version of jquery is there in your application `console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery)`. My guess is you have two live versions of jQuery there.

Comment: I am really supprised to get many comment quickly. Thanks everybody.I solved. Thank Jai. I checked used jquery version. It was 1.6.x. So i changed to use 1.7.1.min. That solved this problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"object don't support 'on'property or method"*

Seems that you have older version of jQuery installed/used in the page.

As i commented at the post, you can try running this line:

```
console.log($.fn.jQuery); // will log used version of jquery like 1.x.x
```

And if this is the case that you have two live versions of jQuery there in the application and older one is been used instead of the updated one. You can either update to the latest one as per your version like **`1.10.X`**:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can go with `jQuery.noConflict(true);` mode to create a new alias for the updated jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(true); // <---new jquery wrapper is j$
    $(document).ready(function(){
         // log versions to see
         console.log($().jquery);
         console.log(j$().jquery); // used here

         j$("table#0").on('click', 'tr', function(){
            // now it should work
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be this will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mu3t8/

```
$(function() {
  $("table").tablesorter({
    debug: true
  });
  $("#major").toggle(
    function() {
      alert('major asc')
    },
    function() {
      alert('major desc')
    }
  );
});
```